# striding through pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, stride

I have a Dataframe of the form

```
date_time                                                            uids
2018-10-16 23:00:00                                                 1000,1321,7654,1321
2018-10-16 23:10:00                                                 7654
2018-10-16 23:20:00                                                  NaN
2018-10-16 23:30:00                                                 7654,1000,7654,1321,1000
2018-10-16 23:40:00                                                 691,3974,3974,323
2018-10-16 23:50:00                                                  NaN
2018-10-17 00:00:00                                                  NaN
2018-10-17 00:10:00                                                  NaN
2018-10-17 00:20:00                                                 27,33,3974,3974,7665,27
```

This is a very big data frame containing the 5 mins time interval and the number of appearances of ids during those time intervals.

I want to iterate over these DataFrame 6 rows at a time (corresponding to 1 hour) and create DataFrame containing the ID and the number of times each id appear during this time.

Expected output is one dataframe per hour information. For example, in the above case dataframe for the hour 23 - 00 will have this form

```
uid   1   2   3   4   5   6

1000  1   0   0   2   0  0
1321  2   0   0   1   0  0
```

and so on

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an exact solution but you could create a pivot table: ids on the index and datetimes on the columns. Then you just have to select the columns you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "date_time": [
        "2018-10-16 23:00:00",
        "2018-10-16 23:10:00",
        "2018-10-16 23:20:00",
        "2018-10-16 23:30:00",
        "2018-10-16 23:40:00",
        "2018-10-16 23:50:00",
        "2018-10-17 00:00:00",
        "2018-10-17 00:10:00",
        "2018-10-17 00:20:00",
    ],
    "uids": [
        "1000,1321,7654,1321",
        "7654",
        np.nan,
        "7654,1000,7654,1321,1000",
        "691,3974,3974,323",
        np.nan,
        np.nan,
        np.nan,
        "27,33,3974,3974,7665,27",
    ],
}
)

df["date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_time"])

df = (
    df.set_index("date_time") #do not use set_index if date_time is current index
    .loc[:, "uids"]
    .str.extractall(r"(?P<uids>\d+)")
    .droplevel(level=1)
) # separate all the ids

df["number"] = df.index.minute.astype(float) / 10 + 1 # get the number 1 to 6 depending on the minutes

df_pivot = df.pivot_table(
    values="number", 
    index="uids", 
    columns=["date_time"], 
) #dataframe with all the uids on the index and all the datetimes in columns.
```

You can apply this to the whole dataframe or just a subset containing 6 rows. Then you rename your columns.

Comment: this simply returns an empty dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `crosstab`:

```
df['uids'] = df['uids'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('uids')
df['date_time'] = df['date_time'].dt.minute.floordiv(10).add(1)
pd.crosstab(df['uids'], df['date_time'], dropna=False)
```

Output:

```
date_time  1  2  3  4  5  6
uids                       
1000       1  0  0  2  0  0
1321       2  0  0  1  0  0
27         0  0  2  0  0  0
323        0  0  0  0  1  0
33         0  0  1  0  0  0
3974       0  0  2  0  2  0
691        0  0  0  0  1  0
7654       1  1  0  2  0  0
7665       0  0  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this with extracting the minutes from your datetime column. Then using `pivot_table` to get your wide format:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

df['minute'] = df['date_time'].dt.minute // 10

piv = (df.assign(uids=df['uids'].str.split(','))
         .explode('uids')
         .pivot_table(index='uids', columns='minute', values='minute', aggfunc='size')
      )
```

```
minute    0    1    2    3    4
uids                           
1000    1.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
1321    2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
27      NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
323     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
33      NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
3974    NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
691     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
7654    1.0  1.0  NaN  2.0  NaN
7665    NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```